# Why isn't my Radio button clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, radio-button, semantic-ui-react

My radio button is not clickable. This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Radio } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const RadioButton = ({ name, label, className, value, onClick, checked, defaultValue }) => (
  <Form.Field>
    <Radio type="radio" label={label} defaultValue={defaultValue} value={value} name={name} className={className} onClick={onClick} checked={checked} />
  </Form.Field>
);

RadioButton.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.instanceOf(undefined)]),
  defaultValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.instanceOf(undefined)]),
  onClick: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.instanceOf(undefined)]),
  checked: PropTypes.bool,
};

RadioButton.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
  value: undefined,
  defaultValue: undefined,
  onClick: null,
  checked: false,
};

export default RadioButton;
```

I can't seem to understand why it's not working. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are permanently setting the `checked` prop to false, so the checkbox never changes checked state. To get it working, you need to control it's checked state through React and manage state in your component (so it can't be a stateless functional component). Here's a simple example:

```
class RadioButton extends React.Component {
  //you can statically set propTypes and defaultProps here if you prefer

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ //ensure correct previous state when async call is batched
      checked: !prevState.checked
    }));
    this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick(); //only execute if exists
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form.Field>
        <Radio {...this.props} onClick={this.handleClick} checked={this.state.checked} /> //{...this.props} passes props to Radio passed to RadioButton
      </Form.Field>
    );
  }
}
```

This will use state and manage checking and unchecking of the radio button. The `checked` prop isn't needed here anymore either.

A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself if the component is supposed to be interactive or change. If yes, then it must have internal state. In this case, the button must be checked and unchecked, which are two *states*. Thus you must manage internal state.